# grouping using regex ending with colon ':'

Tags: python, regex

I have a code which is used to group the words inside the paranthesis,if it has got a same name before paranthesis.

Eg:

```
car __name__(skoda,audi)
car __name__(benz)
```

Outputs:

```
car __name__(skoda,audi,benz)
```

But when a colon `:` provided at the end it doesnot output,

```
car __name__(skoda,audi):       =>no output prints with :
car __name__(benz):
```

I think the problem is with my regex

My code:

```
import collections
class Group:
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
        self.text = []
with open('out.txt','r') as f:
    groups = collections.defaultdict(Group)
    group_pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+(?: __[^__]*__)?)\((.*)\)$')
    current_group = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        m = group_pattern.match(line)
        if m:    # this is a group definition line
            group_name, group_members = m.groups()
            groups[group_name].members.extend(group_members.split(','))
            current_group = group_name
for group_name, group in groups.items():
      print "%s(%s)" % (group_name, ','.join(group.members))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the regex just add `:` at the last and make it as optional by adding `?` next to the colon, so that it would match both type of string formats.

```
(\S+(?: __[^__]*__)?)\((.*)\):?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gX3nX6/3)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a **$** at the end of your regular expression. This forces the regex to look for a pattern ending with a parenthesis.

You can solve it by either dropping the **$** in the regular expression (if you think there will be other trailing characters):

```
(\S+(?: __[^__]*__)?)\((.*)\)
```

Or you can adjust the regular expression to include in the pattern the possibility of a colon appearing 0 or 1 times:

```
(\S+(?: __[^__]*__)?)\((.*)\):?$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regular expressions:

```
f = [ 'car __name__(skoda,audi):\n', 'car __name__(benz):\n' ]
groups = {}
for line in f:
    v =  line.strip().split('__')
    gname, gitems = v[1], v[2]
    gitems = gitems.strip("():").split(",")
    groups[gname] = groups.get(gname, []) + gitems
print groups
```